# Pointing SUB domain to amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, host, amazon-route53

Is possible to point a subdomain for a route 53 host zone? I know how to point a domain, but what about a subdomain? For example, i have:

```
www.mysite.com -> point to other provider
new.mysite.com -> i want point to a aws route 53 hostzone
```

I can't really point all mysite.com and than create the subdomain, this is not a real option.

I create a zone and this are my dns's:

```
placeholder.awsdns-36.com.
placeholder.awsdns-00.net.
placeholder.awsdns-51.org.
placeholder.awsdns-17.co.uk.
```

I didn't find any tutorial. Please, i really NEED this.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add some NS records for your subdomain. A BIND style record set would look like this:

```
new.mysite.com NS placeholder.awsdns-36.com.
new.mysite.com NS placeholder.awsdns-00.net.
etc.
```

Of course exactly how you implement this depends on where/how DNS for mysite.com is managed, but you didn't where that is.